# parse server 502 bad gateway after 1st request

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've made some research (googled and search stackoverflow) for this issue. 
My local parse works perfectly, but when I'm using pm2 on hosting, I'm having 502 bad gateway after doing successful 1st request to Parse. 
How to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix i think, because its a common fault with `PM2` and `parse-server`. When you print the `PM2` logs you will see that there is restart taking place due to `PM2` wanting to write to the `parse-server logs.`

To avoid that, you can totally disable this behavior `(watch: false)` or just ignore the logs and hidden `PM2` directories via `ignore_watch`.

eg:

```
"watch" : true,
"ignore_watch" : ["node_modules", "logs"]
```

Then restart parse-server and you should be good to go.

If its not that,then set `VERBOSE = 1` and print the logs and post it here.